# XSLT generate table out of child nodes in same parent node

Tags: xslt, html-table

I need to generate a table out of one parent node.

The XML snipped looks like this:

```
<persons>
    <name>John</name>
    <age>30</age>
    <city>London</city>
    <name>Jake</name>
    <age>28</age>
    <city>New York</city>
</persons>
```

But sometimes it can look like that:

```
<persons>
    <name>John</name>
    <age>30</age>
    <name>Jake</name>
    <age>28</age>
</persons>
```

The generated table should look the same for both cases, so like these:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>London</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jake</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>New York</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Or in the other case:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jake</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I know what tags can be in `<persons>`.
But I don't know how to do this in xslt.

Comment: Do you know which version of XSLT you can use?

Comment: I am using version 2.0

Comment: @Filburt yes, it's odd, but I can't change it, so I have to find a solution for that... It would be so much easier if there is a <person> element...

Comment: Will the `name` tag always be present for each person?

Comment: @TimC yes, it will be always present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using XSLT 2.0, you can use the `xsl:for-each-group` construct for this, so you are grouping elements starting with the `name` element

Try this XSLT. This assumes `name` will always be present, and be the first element in the group. `age` and `city` need not be present though.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="persons">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>City</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="name">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[self::age]" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[self::city]" /></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I apply templates for each tag? I tried to replace `xsl:value-of` with `xsl:apply-templates` but it's only working for `select="."`

Comment: You need to clarify what the issue is. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTC for an example that uses `xsl:apply-templates`

Comment: That's exactly what I suspected to get. But instead in my template it applies the `age` and `city` template twice. So there is `<td>30 years28 years</td>` and `<td>LondonNew York</td>`. Do you have an idea why? The code should be exactly the same, only the tag names differ.

Comment: Without seeing your code it is impossible to answer. You probably want to ask a new question, I think. Thanks

Comment: The prefix of the namespace seems to be the problem. I try to fix it. If I don't find a solution, I will ask another question. Thank you very much!

Comment: See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTC/3 with the prefix

Comment: You forgot to use the prefix in the group-starting-with clause. It should be `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="dm:name">`, otherwise the statement selects everything in just the one group.